# Python: Which XML parser supports DTD !ENTITY definitions?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-namespaces, minidom

I have the below XML file, currently I am using minidom and I get for the example the `documentElement`'s `tagName` as being `xyz:widget` that tells me that it ignores the [`!ENTITY` definitions](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/fdp-primer/xml-primer-include.html) and thus the`!DOCTYPE` reference.

Which XML parser supports [Document Type Definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) so that  [!ENTITY definitions](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/fdp-primer/xml-primer-include.html) and !DOCTYPE reference will no be ignored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE widget [
<!ENTITY widgets-ns "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
<!ENTITY pass "pass&amp;.html">
]>
<xyz:widget xmlns:xyz="&widgets-ns;">
  <xyz:content src="&pass;"/>
  <xyz:name>bv</xyz:name>
</xyz:widget>
```

So that for the above example, you can get using python the `XML` equivalent:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <content src="pass&amp;.html"/>
  <name>bv</name>
</widget>
```

or to get a `DOM` that has as a `documentElement` as `widget` and its `childNodes` as `content` and `name`, `widget` attribute as `xmlns` with value `http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets`, etc

I probably may not used the correct terminology, but I hope I made  myself clear with the help of the above examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LXML](http://lxml.de/) handles this just fine:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> s = """<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
... <!DOCTYPE widget [
... <!ENTITY widgets-ns "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
... <!ENTITY pass "pass&amp;.html">
... ]>
... <xyz:widget xmlns:xyz="&widgets-ns;">
...   <xyz:content src="&pass;"/>
...   <xyz:name>bv</xyz:name>
... </xyz:widget>
... """
>>> etree.fromstring(s)
<Element {http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets}widget at 7f4de2cc58e8>
>>> etree.fromstring(s).xpath("//xyz:content/@src",
...                           namespaces={"xyz": "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"})
['pass&.html']
```